# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick') が解決できません

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

javascript初心者です。
Firebaseでログイン機能を作っているのですが、Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick')のエラーが出たため色々調べてscriptの読み込みをbody下部に入れてみたり、window.onloadやDOMContentLoadedをやってみたのですが
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick') at window.onload
になるだけでいろいろ考えたのですが分かりませんでした
無知ですみませんがどなたかご教示お願いします。

login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <script type="module">
            // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
            import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.0/firebase-app.js";
            // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
            // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
          
            // Your web app's Firebase configuration
            const firebaseConfig = {
            };
          
            // Initialize Firebase
            const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
          </script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="auth.css">
    </head>
    <body>
<div class="form-wrapper">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="room0/images/wetch-logo-invisible.png" width="255" height="50">
    </div>
    <h1>サインイン</h1>
    <form>
      <div class="form-item">
        <label for="email"></label>
        <input type="email" name="email" required="required" placeholder="メールアドレス" id="email"></input>
      </div>
      <div class="form-item">
        <label for="password"></label>
        <input type="password" name="password" required="required" placeholder="パスワード" id="password"></input>
      </div>
      <div class="button-panel">
        <button type="submit" class="button" id="signin" onclick="signIn()">ログイン</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="form-footer">
      <p><a href="register.html">アカウント作成</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">パスワードを忘れた場合</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="module" src="auth.js"></script>
</body>
```

auth.js

```
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.0/firebase-auth.js"
const auth = getAuth();
window.onload = function (){
document.getElementById("signIn").onclick = function signIn(){
  var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
  signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then(function(){
    console.log("signin successful");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    console.log("error:" + errorCode + errorMessage);
  });
}
}
```

Comment: 見落としてました...
無事動きました！ありがとうございましたm（ _ _ ）m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getElementById("signIn")
```

```
<button ... id="signin" ...>
```

`signIn` というIDが存在しないからだと思います。
（html側に書かれてるIDは `signin` / 大文字小文字が異なるので別物として扱われている）